# how to type component using css emotion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, emotion

I have this component and I can't use the theme with typescript

```
const buttonDisabled = css`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.color};
`;
```

How can I type this component?

```
error:  No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(template: TemplateStringsArray, ...args: CSSInterpolation[]): SerializedStyles', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ theme }: { theme: any; }) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CSSInterpolation'.
      Type '({ theme }: { theme: any; }) => any' is missing the following properties from type 'CSSInterpolation[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 28 more.
```

Answer (score 0):

Take help from their official documentation it have everything related to create a component in emotion https://emotion.sh/docs/styled
and Simplest way to create a component using emotion css is

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'

const Button = styled.button`
  color: turquoise;
`

render(<Button>This my button component.</Button>)
```

pass props

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

export const DIV = styled.div`
  background-color: pink;
  color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <DIV color="blue">Hello World</DIV>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and if u want to only use css

```
import "./styles.css";
import {css} from '@emotion/css';

const color = 'blue';

export const buttonDisabled = css`
  color:${color}
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className={buttonDisabled}>Hello World</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: i need to use = css``

Comment: if u use css`` u can only write css part and u can style your component only u can't create component from it for that u need to use '@emotion/styled'.

Comment: I just want to use the theme, leave the color variable according to the theme

Comment: sharing codepan code for the same

Comment: error, that was the question. Thus the typing error

Comment: I update the answer with example of passing props so in the same way u can pass theme as well

Comment: friend, i need to use emotion's import css, i can't use styled

Comment: oh but u can't create component in CSS but u can create a class and pass the variable color into it and use it in className in other component

Comment: I update the answer check it now I add example for it as well

Comment: I hope this what u want please let me know

Comment: That's basically it, my friend. But I need the 'blue' value to be dynamic with the theme

Comment: yeah so in place of color use ${theme.color}

Comment: did it work for u? If yes please accept my answer and upvote thanks bro

Comment: hey brother i have type problems when doing this. I think I would need to configure something about types.d.ts but I'm not getting it. Can't find theme.color, I use typescript

Thanks